# How do I anchor the legend to floating chart in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

As of right now, if I'm floating the chart, the legend will not float with it. I would like to anchor that legend along side(or maybe even inside) the chart. This way when Im draging my chart into positon, I won't have to do the same with the legend. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each object on the dashboard is independent, and only relevant to the top left corner of the dashboard when floating. You can create containers and move the entire container as per this article:

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-s/dashboards_organize_floatingandtiled.htm

I know anchoring to an object has been an asked for feature in the past going back as far as 2016, that I could find, but I do not know the current in progress status.

Comment: Stryder, your link doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm sure I can find more info on containers though

Comment: Nick T - try https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_organize_floatingandtiled.htm

Comment: Thanks guys. The container does take a few steps but it pretty much solves the problem. I hope Tableau will add an anchoring feature in their upcoming releases.